# derivative of $f(n)=(-1)^n$

Tags: calculus

can this function $f(n)=(-1)^n$ be differentiated?

When trying to find the limit, I could not apply L'Hopital's rule because $\ln (-1)$ is undefined.

Also looking at the range/ outputs of this function, it alternates between -1 and 1. I cannot relate this to the slope/ derivative of the function.

Comment: @peter-foreman I was trying to find the derivative using the definition of derivative as a limit, that is where I got the indeterminate form 0/0

Comment: What is $f(\frac12)$? What about $f(\frac1{100})$?

Comment: @PeterForeman : This function, if defined on $\Bbb Z$ as the notation suggests, is trivially continuous. The problem then is that it is not defined on a continuous domain.

Comment: @LutzL I haven't actually studied continuity of functions $\mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mathbb{Z}$. Are they all trivially continuous? Because I would imagine they all have jump discontinuities unless constant.

Comment: @PeterForeman Indeed, all functions with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ are trivially continuous! This is because there are open neighborhoods around each point $x$ which contain only $x$. Using the epsilon-delta definition makes it clear! See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space

Comment: @Sambo that depends on the topology you assign to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Umberto Well yes; I meant with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be the multi-valued, complex-valued function given by $f(x)=(-1)^x$.  Then, we have

$$f(x)=e^{i(2k+1)x\pi}\tag1$$

for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Differentiating $(1)$ reveals

$$f'(x)=i(2k+1)\pi e^{i(2k+1)x\pi}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman The integers are usually endowed with the discrete topology (power set), on which all functions are continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only makes sense to talk about the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if $f$ is defined in a neighborhood (i.e. an interval) around $x$. Since $f(n) = (-1)^n$ only makes sense for integer values of $n$ (without going into complex numbers), the domain of $f$ must be a discrete set (I.e. a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$). Thus, it doesn't make sense to take the derivative of $f$ at any point in its domain.

Comment: Are you *defining* OP's function for him? Clearly, he meant the domain to be real.

Comment: @Allawonder Indeed, I am making this assumption. This is because, as stated in my answer, it is not possible to define the function $f(x) = a^x$ for $a < 0$ and $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ (in a way that is consistent with the usual exponential function) without appealing to complex numbers. I assumed it was not OP's intent to consider these possibilities, since the level of the question seemed rather basic.

Comment: @Allawonder : The OP is not really clear on what the domain and the function is. Clearly OP thinks about $a^x$ with $a=-1$, but from the remark on the values only considers integer $x$. Unless OP adds more about the raised questions, one can not say with certainty.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, OP is indeed not clear. How ever, the fact that they want to *differentiate* this function suggests strongly that the domain cannot be $\mathbf Z.$

Comment: @Sambo But clearly you did not consider the very apparent fact that OP wants to *differentiate* this expression? How does that tally with your claim that OP has the domain of integers in mind? That looks like an insulting way to interpret OP's question. Nobody differentiates a sequence, LOL!

Comment: @Allawonder : You should not be too fast with the lulz. The theorem of Cesaro-Stolz is essentially l'Hopitals rule (or the extended mean value theorem) for sequences.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for bringing that up! Indeed, I remember problems where to find a limit of a sequence, we would extend it to real numbers, apply L'Hospital's rule, and then get our answer for the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

While there are already answers in the classical sense, i would like to point out that sometimes when you can't do something directly, you may find ways to overcome difficulties, one of such being a derivative of a function defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ or even more ridiculously on $\{q^{n}| n\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ for some $ q\in \mathbb{R}$\ $ \{ \pm 1, 0 \} $.

In the first case there is a discrete derivative: $\Delta f (n) = f(n + 1) - f(n)$ and in the second one there is $q$-derivative: $\Delta_{q}f = \frac{f(qx) - f(x)}{qx - x}$.
Both satisfying usual properties, e.g. linearity, analogues of Leibniz rule(which you can find yourself), derivative is $0$ iff function is constant.

Reasonable question is "and what are they good for?". Answer is: combinatorics, reccurent sequences, $q$-stuff, modern number theory and much more.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function will exists if you can draw a tangent line to the curve at every point.

If you think on $(-1)^n$, its graph has two set of alternate points. Try to draw any imaginary tangent line to the graph and you will realize that there exists a lot of "tangent" lines. Since there is no an unique tangent, you can't define a derivative.